# Drop values saved comma separated in a cell in excel

Tags: excel, csv, dropdown, vba

I have a metadatasheet from which I am setting some parameters from which I am generating pivots. I am selecting these parameters through dropdown lists.

[Here is what my metadata sheet looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KaPQi.jpg)

I am saving the values of dropdown in a comma separated manner in the corresponding cell. For that I have a macro on that sheet which is :

```
 Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

'Set automatic formula calculation ON
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

Dim Oldvalue As String
Dim Newvalue As String
Application.EnableEvents = True
On Error GoTo Exitsub
If Target.Address = "$C$5" Or Target.Address = "$C$6" Or Target.Address = "$C$7" Or Target.Address = "$D$5" Or Target.Address = "$D$6" Or Target.Address = "$D$7" Or Target.Address = "$E$5" Or Target.Address = "$E$6" Or Target.Address = "$E$7" Then
  If Target.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeAllValidation) Is Nothing Then
    GoTo Exitsub
  Else: If Target.Value = "" Then GoTo Exitsub Else
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Newvalue = Target.Value
    Application.Undo
    Oldvalue = Target.Value
      If Oldvalue = "" Then
        Target.Value = Newvalue
      Else
        If InStr(1, Oldvalue, Newvalue) = 0 Then
            Target.Value = Oldvalue & "," & Newvalue
      Else:
        Target.Value = Oldvalue
      End If
    End If
  End If
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exitsub:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

**My issues:**

1) Rather than defining individual cells in the 10th line of macro, is there a way define a range? Basically I am defining all the cells of the range C5:E7 as individual cells using "Or"

2) I am not able to delete individual comma separated values, because while doing so it give me the following error.[A user has restricted values that can be entered into the cell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JALB2.jpg)
I have to entire cell and then select the values again.  Is there a way I can delete only single value?

Comment: For Q1: `If Not Application.Intersect(Target, Me.Range("C5:E7")) Is Nothing Then`

Comment: Thanks Robin...that definitely solves the 1st issue. :)